# Using an String[] in Regex Pattern

Tags: c#, .net

This is my first time dealing with regex. I need to have a string array as apart of a regex pattern. Specifically I’m trying to match a date so the two formats I’m dealing with are `DDTTTTMMM` and `MMMDDTTTT` the month is a *three letter abbreviation* (ex:`DEC`) I can’t control where the month is placed in my input.

Date example for today is `011150DEC` or `DEC011150`

```
String[] months = {“JAN”, “FEB”, …, “DEC”}

String pattern1 = [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][months]; 

String pattern2 = [months][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9];
```

Comment: And what do you need regex for?

Comment: Why don't you use `DateTime.ParseExact` (or `DateTime.TryParseExact`) and let .Net do the work for you?

Comment: Btw: for validation, those patterns would be incorrect. There are no days > 31 and no hours > 23, no minutes > 59 ...

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are not a good for parsing dates; just imagine *leap year* problem.
You can use [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-7.0&ranMID=43674&ranEAID=FE4O7wtxe6g&ranSiteID=FE4O7wtxe6g-yV_X83SpXxe.6n3NE3lxpA&epi=FE4O7wtxe6g-yV_X83SpXxe.6n3NE3lxpA&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2200057_aff_7795_1243925&tduid=(ir__1impw2s6cwkfb29c0gcpuf19xn2xczqafhhcuxt300)(7795)(1243925)(FE4O7wtxe6g-yV_X83SpXxe.6n3NE3lxpA)()&irclickid=_1impw2s6cwkfb29c0gcpuf19xn2xczqafhhcuxt300) instead

```
private static bool TryMyParse(string text, out DateTime result) => 
  DateTime.TryParseExact(
    text,
    new string[] { "ddHHmmMMM", "MMMddHHmm"},
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal,
    out result);
```

Demo:

```
string[] tests = new string[] {
  "011150DEC",
  "DEC011150",
  "abracadabra",
};

var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test,20} => {(TryMyParse(test, out var date) ? date.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm") : "???")}"));

Console.Write(result);
```

Output:

```
           011150DEC => 01 December 2022 11:50
           DEC011150 => 01 December 2022 11:50
         abracadabra => ???
```

If you insist on regular expression, let's build the `pattern` step by step:

```
// Let's use correct abbreviations instead of hardcoded ones
string months = string.Join("|", CultureInfo
  .InvariantCulture
  .DateTimeFormat
  .AbbreviatedMonthNames
  .Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m)))
     .ToUpper();

// Subpatterns for days, hours, minutes and months
string dd = "(?<dd>[0-3][0-9])"; // 00 and 39 day are still possible...
string HH = "(?<HH>[0-2][0-9])"; // 27 hour is still possible...
string mm = "(?<mm>[0-5][0-9])";
string MMM = $"(?<MMM>{months})";

// Time to construct the final pattern which should match 
// either ddHHmmMMM or MMMddHHmm:
string pattern = string.Join("|",
  $"(^{dd}{HH}{mm}{MMM}$)",
  $"(^{MMM}{dd}{HH}{mm}$)");
```

Have a look at the monster (which, however, let days be `00` and `39` allowes hours to be `26`):

```
Console.Write(pattern);
```

Output:

```
(^(?<dd>[0-3][0-9])(?<HH>[0-2][0-9])(?<mm>[0-5][0-9])(?<MMM>JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)$)|(^(?<MMM>JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)(?<dd>[0-3][0-9])(?<HH>[0-2][0-9])(?<mm>[0-5][0-9])$)
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, using simple string concatenation:

```cs
string[] months = {"JAN", "FEB", "DEC"};
string monthsGroup = "(?:" + String.Join("|", months) + ")";
string pattern1 = @"\d{6}" + monthsGroup;
string pattern2 = monthsGroup + @"\d{6}";

Console.WriteLine(pattern1);    // \d{6}(?:JAN|FEB|DEC)
Console.WriteLine(pattern2);    // (?:JAN|FEB|DEC)\d{6}
```

Of course, you could alternatively use `String.Format` or interpolated strings as you prefer.